# Can I send some initial when establishing SignalR connection?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I know I can send this data later with `$.connection.send(value)`, but can I send some initial value during the SignalR connection establishment ?

i.e.:

```
var con = $.connection(url);
con.start(value);
```

Or maybe using the connection string ? like:

```
var con = $.connection(url + '&data=' + data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the docs at https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client:

```
connection.start(function() {
    console.log("connection started!");
});

connection.stop();

// The callback will be raised again!
connection.start();
```

Looks like you can get a callback to the connection as soon as it is ready and hopefully use it through the **this** object reference to make the first call:

```
connection.start(function() {
    this.ServerMethodCall(someValue);
};
```

**edit: added sample code**

Comment: I don't understand. where do I pass the `value` I want to send to the server ?

Comment: I edited the answer to include the code. I didn't test it, but got made it from the docs so you should make sure it works as you expected.

Comment: The `this` object has no such method (`ServerMethodCall`).. ?

Comment: ServerMethodCall should be the method you defined on your Signal R server hub